# Move Highstock columns between x-axis ticks

Tags: highcharts

I've an API that is returning the following data:

```
[1466274600000, 166.409],
[1466274900000, 138.266],
[1466275200000, 160.668],
[1466275500000, 147.300],
[1466275800000, 147.778],
[1466276100000, 136.043]
```

I've loaded this into Highstock, which gives me this chart

[image]

However, the values are actually the rate of change between the timestamp and the next timestamp. So, the difference between the value at 1466274600000 and 1466274900000 is 166.409, etc. so I'd like the charts to represent this by appearing over the gap between the ticks.

[image]

Is this possible? I can change the output of the API if necessary...

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bLrah/157/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/strince/bLrah/159/

```
    var data = [
      [1466274600000, 166.409],
      [1466274900000, 138.266],
      [1466275200000, 160.668],
      [1466275500000, 147.300],
      [1466275800000, 147.778],
      [1466276100000, 136.043]
    ];
var columnWidth = $("#chart").width() / data.length;

...

      plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 1,
                borderWidth: 1,
                pointWidth: columnWidth
            }
        },
```